# Kafka queue message processing

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

I have an interesting problem to solve related to Kafka queue message processing. Here is the problem: I have a topic lets say "Topic1" and the corresponding consumer "Consumer1". Consumer1 is processing messages from Topic1 however once the total messages processed reach a certain limit (lets say #1000) it needs to stop processing but in a way that all the subsequent messages received should be again processed the next day.

In a way we have a limit on how many messages can be processed in day, plus the overflow of messages should be carried forward to the next day for processing.

Another important thing is, we also have a ResponseTopic1 wherein consumers are listening for the response whether the messages being sent has been processed or carried forward to the next day.

To start with, I am thinking of 3 topics here: Topic1, ResponseTopic1 and WaitingTopic1. Once the limit is breached, we can move messages from RT1 to WT1. Consumer for WT1 would be dynamically started at the start of the day and would start processing messages from the waiting queue.

I know this solution is not at all perfect hence posting here as I am thinking more on this. Please share if you have solved any such problem before. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have one Topic1 then only one consumer in a consumer group can consume messages from the topic. If you want to limit the number of messages (say #1000), in the consumer, you can count for that and stop/sleep the consumer. You should handle the commit offset also. Moving messages from Topic1 to RT1 and WT1 maybe complex, Kakfa does not support you to do that by default.

Comment: Hi @NangSaigon, I thought of this approach however, blocking the consumer is not an option for me because the producers need an acknowledgement of whether the messages has been processed or carried forward to the next day processing.

Comment: Note that the producer can not know whether a message is processed or not. Producer may only know whether a message is delivered to Broker or not.

Comment: We have another topic "ResponseTopic" wherein the consumer sends back an acknowledgement for a particular message so that the producer application knows the status of the message sent (processed or carried forward).